# checkbox contact form problems

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am newbie. I am trying to create a checkbox contact form with php, but suddenly my code dose not work. Can someone give a hint where should i find my mistake? I do not recieve any errors or something like that. Just not recieving any mails...

```
 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php" enctype="text/plain"> 
<div class="cell">
<div class="check">
    <input id="check-0" type="checkbox" name="reparatur[]" value="Akku" />
    <p class="problBer">Akku<label for="check-0" class="cena">€79</label></p>

    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="cell">
<div class="check">
    <input id="check-1" type="checkbox" name="reparatur[]" value="Display"/>
    <p class="problBer">Display<label for="check-1" class="cena">€295</label></p>
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="cell">
<div class="check">
    <input id="check-2" type="checkbox" name="reparatur[]" value="Fehlerdiagnose"/>
      <p class="problBer">Fehlerdiagnose<label for="check-2" class="cena"> €20</label></p>
     <div class="mask"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <table style="width:95%;">
   <tr>

  <td valign="top">
   <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="close" style="left: 83%; position: absolute; color: black; cursor: pointer; top: 0;"></i>
   <label for="name">Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30" style="width: 180px; background-color: #fff;">

   </td>

 </tr>

   <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" style="width: 180px; background-color: #fff;">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" style="width: 180px; background-color: #fff;">

</td>

</tr>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="adresse">Adresse*</label>

  </td>

  <td valign="top">

   <input  type="text" name="adresse" maxlength="30" size="30" style="width: 180px; background-color: #fff;">

 </td>

 </tr>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

 <label for="comments">Kommentare *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

 <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" style="width: 180px;"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">

  <input type="submit" value="Bestellen" class="bestButDiv" style="width: 90%; float: left;">

 </td>

</tr>

</table>


    </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
  <?php
   error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "mail@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Contact form";
$email_from = "from@from.com";

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($_POST["name"])."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($_POST["email"])."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($_POST["telephone"])."\n";
$email_message .= "Adresse: ".clean_string($_POST["adresse"])."\n";
$email_message .= "Reparieren: ".implode(" ", $_POST['reparatur'])."\n";
$email_message .= "Kommentare: ".clean_string($_POST["comments"])."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>


<center>
  <br>
  Danke für Ihre Nachricht.So schnell wie möglich erhalten Sie  eine bestätigung von uns.<br>
 <a href="index.html">HOME</a></center>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Your questions is very broad and without debugging feedback, we are going to be here for an unnecessary amount of time.

Comment: I do not recieve any errors or something like that. Just not recieving any mails... after clicking on submit im getting a blank page

Comment: Where you are trying this code on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the variables **$email_to** and **$email_from** with the correct emails?

Answer (score -1):

Well it should send you an email , but the only reason it won't work is if you are using it on localhost.

Comment: Confusing answer; that is far from being the only possible reason.

Comment: no, im using it on web hosting. but i just uploaded all my files from localhost to ftp folder of my website and still getting nothing. And im getting errors like Multiple Choices

The document name you requested could not be found on this. So when i have an iframe with src to .php file which is on the same folder it gives me that error

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/300-multiple-choice-error-cant-find-pages-other-than-index

Comment: but if i move requested .php file in folder and change src path then it works